# Doing addition and subtraction with tensor diagrams?

Tags: tensor-calculus, quantum-computer, tensor-network

Tensor diagrams are a beautiful and useful tool for making calculations with tensors, up until you need to contract with the sum or difference of two tensors, at which point it seems to become awful. Is there an standard or elegant way to diagrammatically notate the sum or difference of two tensors?

Comment: Read Penrose's book (Road to Reality), but did not pay attention to them then. Thanks for remiding me. Unfortunatelly I can not help, only thank you for a good question

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/257240/

Answer (score 1):

There is *a* way to notate the sum or difference of two tensors. You draw one diagram, and then you write a plus or a minus sign, and then you draw the second diagram. This is fairly standard, but definitely not elegant. As far as I know there is no elegant way to write the sum.

One trick that is sometimes elegant is to introduce the "1s vector" $(1,\dots,1)$. A tensor connected to the 1s vector is the sum of the tensors corresponding to each basis vector.